# ビルドしてiPodにインストールすると画面が回転しなくなる

Tags: monaca, jquery, ios9

iPodに有線で接続してデバッグしている時は、画面の向きが問題なく切り換わっているのですが、
（画面の回転は問題なく行われる）
そのソースをビルドしてiPodにインストールすると画面の向きが縦のままで横向きにならない
（iPodを横向きにして画面が回転しない）
現象が出ています。
何か設定が間違っているのでしょうか？
ご教授お願い致します。
ちなみに、
iPodは、iOS 9.3.2です。
monacaの設定としては
「Cordovaプラグイン」は、

- BarcodeScanner
- Monaca Plugin
- Splashscreen
- Whitelist

の４つを指定しています。

「JS/CSSコンポーネント」は、

- Cordova(phoneGap)Loader Ver=1.0.0
- Monaca Core Utilitu Ver=2.0.4

の２つを設定しています。

ソースはJQueryMobileで、記述しています。
index.htmlファイルのheadに次の様にリンクしています。

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js" ></script>
```

画面は`<section>`タブで構成しています。

Comment: 上記質問文では記載されていないですが、気になるのが、`<script src="components/loader.js"></script>`は追加されていますか？これがないと`Cordova`と`monaca`の初期化がされないです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordovaのフレームワークはバージョン5でしょうか？

でしたら、ファイル一覧にある`config.xml`を開き
下記の記載があることを確認して下さい。
もし、無いようであれば追加してください。
追加する場合は`</widget>`の直ぐ上の行当たりが良いです。

```
  <platform name="ios">
    <preference name="orientation" value="all"/>
  </platform>
```

中身の説明はIDE画面上部の"設定"より
"iOSアプリ設定"を選択し、一番下の"その他"に"画面の向き:"の欄で説明しております。
Cordova5未満の場合は此方から確認してください。
また、その下の注意書きの説明を引用すると下記になります。

> 縦横両方対応の場合は上記のvalueに「all」、横向きのみの場合は「landscape」、縦向きのみの場合は「portrait」を指定します。

設定が記載されていないとデフォルトの縦固定になりますね。

---

あとは、無いとは思いますが端末側のOSのメニューの回転ロックがかかっていないか？
回転しないように固定するプラグインを入れていないかなどですかね